# Can't ssh, connection terminates immediately with exit status 254

Tags: shell, ssh, ulimit

The most recent thing I remember is changing the soft and hard memlock ulimit to unlimited. Now I can't ssh into the machine.

This is the ssh log.

```
Authenticated to IP ([IP]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_CTYPE = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
Last login: Wed Aug  6 07:18:07 2014 from IP-SOURCE
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
Connection to IP closed.
Transferred: sent 4256, received 2504 bytes, in 0.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9616.9, received 5658.0
debug1: Exit status 254
```

I have tried the following unsuccessfully till now, before posting here:

1. Trying for a norc noprofile login by `ssh user@host 'bash --noprofile'`
2. Forcing a tty by `ssh -t user@host`
3. Moved the bash_profile. Tried sshing by `ssh user@host`.
4. Renaming the `limits.conf` file in hopes that it won't be read.
5. Restarted ssh server.
6. Run a command via `knife` as `knife ssh "name:server" "come_command"`
7. `ssh user@host 'ulimit -l 64'`, `ssh user@host 'ulimit -S -l 64'`, `ssh user@host 'ulimit -H -l 64'`, `ssh user@host 'exec ulimit -H -l 64'`

I am not sure if this way of running commands inline: `ssh user@host "some_command"` works, because I can't get a simple directory listing. I also tried rebooting by `ssh user@host 'reboot'` but don't think the command was executed. I restarted the machine from AWS also, but unsuccessful.

Is it a lost cause trying to ssh? Is there any way I can ssh into the server?

Comment: If the login shell of the remote user is bash, then bash always reads ~/.bashrc over ssh. There's no way around that. Can you sftp there and check/alter your bashrc that way?

Comment: Tried sftp using CyberDuck, got the `SSH_FXP_INIT` error code.

Comment: You can also get more detailed output using the `-v` option, or for more, the `-vv` option of for even more, then `-vvv` option. E.g. `ssh -vvv user@host`. That may give you a better idea of where things are going wrong.

Comment: Tried that. This is where I got the log from.

Comment: Do you have any other file (FTP/HTTP...?) or shell (console?) access to the machine which you can use?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Unfortunately, not. Its a machine hosted on AWS, and only SSH access is allowed. I tried SFTP, but I got the error as commented above.

Comment: If `ssh host 'echo foo >&2'` doesn't output anything, I don't think there's much you can do.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too. Have started migrating data off that server. Will play with it once I'm done migrating.

Answer (score 17):

Try to change

```
UsePAM yes
```

on

```
UsePAM no
```

in 
`/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (for CentOS)

Comment: It works, but why?

Comment: sorry, but i dont remember the reason)

Comment: Is SELinux in play here ?  Wondering if the context of `/etc/security/limits.conf` got hosed, and pam can't use it any more.

Comment: If you are using a distribution using `systemd` this is a bad solution IMHO. This will prevent `logind`to a open a session and when/if the user is rebooting the machine, some processes started as the user will not be stopped as expected.

Comment: In my case, the reason is the user Hard Open Fils Limit per processor is bigger than the `nr_open`. (`nr_open` is reset when restarting the machine): you can check the `nr_open` by `cat /proc/sys/fs/nr_open`, and hard open files `ulimit -Hn`. If you still want the ssh login user use the Hard Open File Config, you need to increase `nr_open`: `sudo sysctl -w fs.nr_open=NUM_BIGGER_THAN_HARD`

Comment: This helped me as well (Debian 8).

Comment: See here for a possible reason why `UsePAM yes` works:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/673153/sshd-what-are-the-practical-effects-of-setting-usepam-no

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem, I seemed to only see following strange message:

```
client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0.
```

User I was trying to `ssh` into **didn't have a default shell**.

I ran the following:

```
chsh -s $(which sh) username
```

And then I was able to `ssh`.

**Note:**

Running `su username` was returning exit-code `1` (was failing) and now it just works.

Comment: Holy crap that's cryptic! This was my problem as well. I tried making a "system" user (no HOME and no SHELL) to use SFTP with and I could authenticate but I couldn't use SFTP or SCP or SSH. This fixed my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was changed the Open files configuration in kernel parameter file /etc/security/limits.conf to unlimited and lost the connectivity.

After reverting it back to the normal for root user i got the connectivity back.

```
Wrong Example:
## Example hard limit for max opened files
*        hard   nofile unlimited
root     hard   nofile  unlimited
## Example soft limit for max opened files
*        soft   nofile unlimited
root     soft   nofile unlimited

Correct Ex:
## Example hard limit for max opened files
*        hard   nofile 16000
root     hard   nofile 16000
## Example soft limit for max opened files
*        soft   nofile 16000
root     soft   nofile 16000
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was the zsh shell that stopped working on the server end. However, I was still able to send commands to verify it: `ssh -t username@host 'echo $0'`

Requested bash `ssh -t username@host 'bash -l'` stopped the server from terminating the session.

Comment: This worked to stop it from exiting. But still don't know why it exited. Is the fact that this worked insight into the why?

Comment: Might be your .zshrc or profile or another file that is automatically run after logging in that triggers your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered this on **Mac OS X** where the configuration in `~/.bashrc` had an problem which caused `ssh` to work, but `sftp` to **not** work. @stéphane-chazelas seems to have the right idea in the comments above.

On the remote system via SSH, rename `~/.bashrc` to `~/.bashrc-MOVED` and try it again and see if it works; then restore `~/.bashrc` and determine the issue.

On my system the `~/.bashrc` contained this:

```
if [ -z "$PS1" ] ; then
    exit
fi
```

Which was the likely culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today.  First thing I noticed was `/var/log` was at 100%.

I fixed that and it didn't solve the issue. I couldn't `ssh` in nor could I login via the GUI, but I could <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to CLI and login that way.  I typed `startx` and received an error that `/tmp/.X0-lock` existed.

I removed that file (technically I removed everything from `/tmp`) and I was able to login via GUI and also via `ssh`.

Comment: Thanks! In my case it was `/home` filled up to 100% which I have detected by using `df -h` on CentOS 7.