# sshd: what are the practical effects of setting "UsePAM no"

Tags: ssh, login, sshd, pam

in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, PAM is enabled by default on Debian 10:

```
UsePAM yes
```

In a situation when I don't want to allow login with password or kerberos, and only want to allow SSH key authentication, does it still have any advantage to enable `PAM` in sshd? Or, would it simplify the process and perhaps make it more secure, if `UsePAM` is set to no?

What would be the practical effects of disabling PAM in sshd? Would I notice any difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contrary to what the manpage (and another answer) claims, `UsePAM yes` not only *allows* you to run sshd as a non-root user, but also allows a sshd running as non-root user to perform *password authentication* (for the same user it's running as) via the setuid `/sbin/unix_chkpwd` program.

The latter of which is quite unexpected.

```
user$ /usr/sbin/sshd -f /dev/null -p 9009 -h ~/.ssh/id_rsa
user$ /usr/sbin/sshd -f /dev/null -o UsePAM=yes -p 7007 -h ~/.ssh/id_rsa

user$ ssh -p 7007 localhost
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:7007 ([::1]:7007)' can't be established.
...
Password: <correct password>
Linux deb11 5.10.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.46-4 (2021-08-03) x86_64
...
user$  <I'm logged in!>
user$ ^D
Connection to localhost closed.


user$ ssh -p 9009 localhost
The authenticity of host '[localhost]:9009 ([::1]:9009)' can't be established.
...
user@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@localhost's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
user@localhost's password:
user@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password,keyboard-interactive).
user$
```

Comment: my ssh daemon runs as root (default setting on Debian 10). How can I change to run as non-root user? According to this thread, there used to be an option `UsePrivilegeSeparation`, which is now deprecated:  https://serverfault.com/a/861842

Answer (score 6):

The [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) explains `UsePAM` does not only offer authentication, but also session processing. There are a lot of [PAM modules](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam) which offer a wide range of functionality, including automatic keyring unlocking, mounting file-systems, decrypting private data, selectively permitting logon,…

In ancient times, when `UsePAM` was set to "yes", sshd required root priviledges. Depending on the use-case, running as a non-root user may help with security or configuration.

I can imagine there are situations when this can come in handy. For example, git uses ssh as a transport protocol. I may want to setup a git server, but I do not want to manage the git users via PAM at all.

Comment: The manual says "If UsePAM is enabled, you will not be able to run sshd(8) as a non-root user.". I do expect the manpages do be correct.

Comment: This is a general question not directed towards a particular distribution. You provided two examples which are indeed insightful. But what about any other distribution? If a Debian package manager changed the software's behaviour and did not update the man-page accordingly, we should probably file a bug. Moreso if this was changed upstream. If I started questioning man-pages and double checked on a daily basis, I probably would not get any work done.

Comment: I just looked and found out [this information](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/commit/1dcff9a3a8891db8d7fce77e43e675ce60e0fe44) is from 2004 and probably outdated. Will you file a bug?

Answer (score 4):

I looked into the source of OpenSSH for this.

It seems that having UsePAM might indirectly or directly leak your env according to the `auth-pam.c` comment I found here in lines 378-382 ([link here](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/7cc3fe28896e653956a6a2eed0a25d551b83a029/auth-pam.c)):

```
         /*
         * XXX this possibly leaks env because it is not documented
         * what pam_putenv() does with it. Does it copy it? Does it
         * take ownweship? We don't know, so it's safest just to leak.
         */
```

Also in the same source code I found this interesting content:

```
/*
     * Some silly PAM modules (e.g. pam_time) require a TTY to operate.
     * sshd doesn't set the tty until too late in the auth process and
     * may not even set one (for tty-less connections)
     */
```

It also seems that password authentication is attempted via PAM on line 1351 and a anti-timing attacks mitigation is used in this code.

Since it's defined in a if clause all this `auth-pam.c` code does not get executed so I would set to no if your security settings allow you to.

So in my opinion I would rather set it to no and don't lose sleep over it anymore.

## Other opinions

There's also this opinion: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1259848/

It seems that SSH public key auth might fail if you setup your settings badly:
https://serverfault.com/questions/475880

I would also recommend reading this conclusion at the end of the `Configuring accounts` section:

https://arlimus.github.io/articles/usepam/

Comment: @zevzek feel free to edit my answer